# Modeling Json objects of Polymorphic types

Tags: json, rest, api-design

I am building an REST API that accepts a shape Json. This API computes area based on the type of the shape and parameters.

Between the below two ways, which is a better way of modeling the request json?

**Option 1**

```
{
    "shape": {
        "type": "RECTANGLE",
        "value": {
            "length": "x",
            "breadth": "y"
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
{
    "shape": {
        "type": "RECTANGLE",
        "length": "x",
        "breadth": "y"
    }
}
```

In my option

Option 1

- Nice segregation between the type of the shape and value. But other than readability of the request Json, I am not sure if this is a huge benefit.

Option - 2

- Lighter than option 1; lesser fields as value is not explicitly mentioned.

What are the advantages and disadvantages between two options?

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: I don't think it really matters? Maybe you have you give a clearer example of cases where you think it does. This feels mostly like an aesthetic/subjective decision.